# AWS Cognito : User creation and username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I am trying to understand AWS Cognito settings in CloudFormation (in fact SAM).

I have used the following settings :

```
Resources:
  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Sub ${Project}-${Env}-CognitoUserPool
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      Schema:
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: email
          Required: false
  CognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: 'AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient'
    Properties:
      ClientName: !Sub ${Project}-${Env}-CognitoUserPoolClient
      GenerateSecret: false
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
```

I understand this should allow users to use their email as their username.  And indeed, I could create a user through the AWS Cognito console using an email as my username.

However, AWS Cognito still creates a UUID for the username as shown herebelow :

[image: AWS Cognito user UUID]

and I can't sign-in using my email as I receive an error :

```
{"__type":"UserNotFoundException","message":"User does not exist."}
```

If I use the UUID, then I have no error and log in. Any idea what I should change to make the email work as a Sign-in option ?

Comment: possible that the `Required: false` ought to be `true`

Comment: no it does not seem to be the issue. Weirdly, if I create a user using the template like this : 

  CognitoUserPoolTestUser:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser"
    Properties:
      Username: my.name@myemail.com
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool

then I can sign-in using the email ...

Comment: Chalk it up to wonkiness in the console.  Whenever I create a user in there,  i have to use the same email address for the username and the email.  The username value always winds up being a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

I did this some time ago using AliasAttributesinstead of UsernameAttributes, this allows to use regular usernames (or uuid in my case) and email.

```
 AliasAttributes: 
    - 'email'
```

Comment: From what I have understood, this is the "old way" of doing things. The UserNameAttributes is the new option AFAIK

Comment: UsernameAttributes works fine in the newer cli's. Keep using this.  @FenryrMKIII Try changing that false yet?